# Rails syntax errors when copy and pasting code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, copy-paste, atom-editor

I have noticed that when people copy and paste code chunks to use in their code(my students) there are often invisible syntax errors. The errors are invisible and unless I ask them if they have copy and pasted I can not see any issues. To resolve the problem we delete everything and write the code instead of copy and pasting.

So my question is... Why are there "invisible" syntax errors when you copy and paste? are there special characters which are not showing up in our editor(Atom and sublime)?

Comment: Maybe enable "Show Invisibles" in the Settings View.  But, I doubt that would cause syntax errors, just linting errors.

Comment: Yeh that is a good thought though... thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass through a plain-text editor (notepad or TextEdit) and see what happens.
Pay particular attention to quotes (single or double), some editors use special open/close quotes!

Comment: See also line endings.  If they've copied code off the web then special web characters like web quotes (the slanty ones) and emdashes (longer versions of normal minus signs) can be introduced, along with various other special characters.

Comment: Yeh it seems interesting... The code did not contain ` or the other special characters... but your suggestion for using notepad/textedit seems like the best idea so I will accept.